# Scope / order of assignment involving `.SDcols`

Tags: r, data.table

Sometimes when trying to replace a bunch of columns by some function of themselves, I want to try an in-place assignment for parsimony, but it doesn't work.

E.g: `dt<-data.table(id=1:5,asdf=rnorm(5),hjkl=rnorm(5))`; the standard approach is to use `:=` and `.SDcols`:

```
dt[,c("asdf","hjkl"):=lapply(.SD,median),.SDcols=c("asdf","hjkl")]
# - or - 
vars<-c("asdf","hjkl")
dt[,(vars):=lapply(.SD,median),.SDcols=vars]
```

But I'm tempted to combine the steps of the latter approach, *a la*:

```
dt[,(vars<-c("asdf","hjkl")):=lapply(.SD,mean),.SDcols=vars]
# - or -
dt[,(vars):=lapply(.SD,mean),.SDcols=vars<-c("asdf","hjkl")]
```

But both fail: `object 'vars' not found`.

Why didn't either of these attempts work?

My first thought was about scope of assignment, but then I'd think one would work while the other wouldn't--i.e., `vars` is declared first with either `.SDcols` or the LHS of `:=`, and is only subsequently available to the other procedure. But both seem local.

Comment: I'm wonder why you want to do this.

Comment: I'm not surprised to see that they don't work. `[.data.table` evaluates its arguments jointly for efficiency reasons, so I doubt it will maintain a feature like this deliberately (even if you do manage to find a workaround that works right now). There's a FR to allow `(.SDcols):=` so that you won't have to type it twice, though. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/795

Comment: @Frank thanks, that FR seems the better solution for what I'm going for.

Answer (score -1):

why not?

```
dt[, .(asdf, hjkl)][, lapply(.SD, mean)]
```

Comment: this won't work if we use `:=` in the second link of the chain--assignment will be done to a temporary `data.table`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico: Why did you down vote? You could create new `data.table` then merge to original one.

Comment: merging=copying; my original examples work and sidestep copying, they're just more long-winded than I preferred.